# Sonatype Nexus cleanup task in Waiting status

Tags: nexus, sonatype, nexus3

We've configured cleanup policies in Sonatype Nexus 3.22.1-02 and also created tasks Cleanup service Admin - Cleanup repositories AND also Admin - Compact blob store and ran them manually but they are still in waiting status after a couple of hours. This is not a scheduled task.

Is there a way to understand what is holding them up and give them a push, or cancel and rerun? TIA.

Answer (score 2):

Task status *Waiting* means the task has completed and is waiting for next run. Whether last run succeeded or failed will be shown in *Last result* field.

In the screenshot below you can see that the last time the task run was on January 21, it completed successfully and it took 0 seconds to complete. Now the task is waiting for the next run that will happen on January 22.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up!